# Can I use an the addition inference rule combined with an existential quantifier?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Can I turn $\exists xA(x)$ into $\exists x\big(A(x) \lor B(x)\big)$ using the addition inference rule?

Answer (score 1):

It is not equivalent, but holds following:
$$\exists x A(x) \Rightarrow \left[ \exists x A(x) \lor \exists xB(x) \right] \Leftrightarrow \exists x\big(A(x) \lor B(x)\big)$$